# TransmitFile with filename containing spaces

Tags: asp.net, string, httpresponse, response.transmitfile

In C# ASP.Net Website, to transfer the file to client I am using

```
String file_path = Server.MapPath("~/files/"+file_name); 
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + file_Name);
HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(file_path);        
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

It is working perfectly, but when the file name contains any spaces the downloaded file has a name only up to the first word. For ex: If my file name is `"This is demo.txt"` then the downloaded file name becomes `"This"` with no extension. Hence the user downloading it is not able to identify its type.
How can we avoid happening it for file name containing spaces?

I tried using

```
String file_path = "'"+Server.MapPath("~/files/"+file_name)+"'";
```

But it didn't work.

Also its not possible for me to replace ( with '_' or '-') or remove all the spaces present in the file name which are present on the server.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should enclose the filename in quotes.

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + file_Name + "\"");
```

And if you are using VS2015 or later, you can make it a bit tidier with string interpolation:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", $"attachment;filename=\"{file_Name}\"");
```

Also, the filename in the header does not have to be the same as the name of the file. The filename in the header is only a suggestion to the user.

For full details, see [RFC 6266](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266) "Use of the Content-Disposition Header Field in the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP)," especially with regard to which characters may cause problems in a filename.